# How to use widget in wagtail admin models.CharField

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I have a `forms.CharField` that uses a widget, as follows:

```py
    address = forms.CharField(
        required=False, max_length=100, label="Address",
        error_messages={'required': ERROR_MSG},
        widget=...   # <-- this line
        )
    )
```

I need to use a widhet in a models.CharField, but I am getting errors saying that it doesn't accept widget.

like this:

```py
    address = models.CharField(
        required=False, max_length=100, label="Address",
        error_messages={'required': ERROR_MSG},
        widget=...   # <-- this line
        )
    )
```

How can I use widget inside models.CharField?

Answer (score 0):

Django has two classes named CharField: forms.CharField and models.CharField. In your top example you are using forms.CharField and passing it a widget. But inside Wagtail, you have Django's models.CharField and that class does NOT take a widgets argument.

The Wagtail equivalent of Django's Form class is the edit handler which you customize using Panels. The built in Panels are described in the [Panel types documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/panels.html). Hopefully that will lead you to the code you would need to extend to port your Django widget into Wagtail.